# CSS: Align bottom of child element to top of parent element (above it on Y axis) while the child has variable height

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to align (with pure CSS/SASS) **bottom** of child element to the **top** of parent element while the child has **variable height**? I want to achieve a popover that is placed above (Y-axis) of parent.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        Bottom border of this should always be on top 
        border of parent - regardless of child's height 
    </div>
</div>
```

I can offset child against `relative` parent with the `position: absolute` and `top: someOffset`, but this requires either dynamic offset calculation in js (I don't have any idea how to do it with `calc()`) or a fixed height of child, but then as the child changes height it will overflow the parent or leave a gap between them.

Comment: transform:translateX(-100%) with top:0 on child element?

Comment: Yes it worked! :D Thank you! Please put your hint as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to solve this:

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.one {
  bottom: 100%;
}

.two {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}


/* this one is hacky but can be useful in some cases */
.three {
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child one">
    Bottom border of this should always be on top border of parent - regardless of child's height
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child two">
    Bottom border of this should always be on top border of parent - regardless of child's height
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="child three">
    Bottom border of this should always be on top border of parent - regardless of child's height
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you started is also fine, just do it this way, using `bottom`:

```css
#parent {
 border: 1px solid red;
 position: relative;
 margin: 100px 0;
}
#child {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    Parent
    <div id="child">
        Bottom border of this should always be on top 
        border of parent - regardless of child's height 
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/1mn6a9eb/3/).

Comment: Thank's! That works too! I already accepted different answer, but I voted yours up as well.